# Group Concat from a select statement

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if my method is possible, but i'm trying to do a group_concat on a select statement that concats 2 fields. I get the error: Subquery returns more than 1 row each time. Can anyone help me as to a solution, or better way around this.

```
select t.recnum, (select group_concat((select concat(b.origtests,'^', d.name) as testing
                from order_origtests b
                join profile c on c.code = b.origtests
                join department d on d.recnum = c.dept
               )))
            FROM order_ t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put `SELECT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`. It should be

```
select t.recnum, (
    select group_concat(concat(b.origtests,'^', d.name))
    from order_origtests b
    join profile c on c.code = b.origtests
    join department d on d.recnum = c.dept
    ) AS testing
FROM order_ t
```

Note that your subquery isn't correlated to anything in `t`, so you'll get the same `testing` column for every `recnum`.